# sql trigger - restrict by time

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want this trigger to work only between a certain time and another time (say 6am-10pm). please help!

```
ALTER TRIGGER [db].[el] ON [Reports].[db].[stat] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [Reports].[db].[el]
            (
               [StationID]
              ,[Count]

              )
 SELECT i.StationID,
        i.[EmptyDockCount],
        GETDATE(),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        i.[LastUpdateDate],
 FROM INSERTED i
 INNER JOIN DELETED d
 on d.StationID = i.StationID
 INNER JOIN DBOS.dbo.StationDim bsd
 ON bsd.StationID = i.StationID
 WHERE i.[Count] = 0
 AND d.[count] <> 0

 ;
```

Comment: wrap with `IF DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) BETWEEN ... AND ... `?

Comment: You have an inner join to DELETED but you also have this defined as an INSERT trigger. The deleted table will always be empty during an insert. You should fix the logic or don't bother with an insert trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

This is the key statement CONVERT(TIME, Getdate()) BETWEEN '6:00:00.0000000' AND '22:00:00.0000000'

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [db].[el]
    ON [Reports].[db].[stat]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF CONVERT(TIME, Getdate()) BETWEEN '6:00:00.0000000' AND '22:00:00.0000000'
          BEGIN
              INSERT INTO [Reports].[db].[el]
                          ([StationID],
                           [Count])
              SELECT i.StationID,
                     i.[EmptyDockCount],
                     Getdate(),
                     NULL,
                     NULL,
                     i.[LastUpdateDate]
              FROM   INSERTED i
                     INNER JOIN DELETED d
                             ON d.StationID = i.StationID
                     INNER JOIN DBOS.dbo.StationDim bsd
                             ON bsd.StationID = i.StationID
              WHERE  i.[Count] = 0
                     AND d.[count] <> 0
          END;
```